# How can I change key when I push data to firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to change key when I push data to firebase realtime database. How can I change ? I'm trying push data without key.

My Database :

```
Deneme/ driverid/( key ) {data ....}
```

My Code:

```
var driverid =getInputVal('driverid');
                var newmesajRef = mesajsRef.child(driverid).push();
                   newmesajRef.set({
                       driverid: driverid,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `push()` is to auto generate a unique key.  If you know exactly where you want to write your data, just build a reference to the location you want, `set()` your data directly at that location, and don't use `push()` at all.

So for exammple, this will write the new data straight under the `driverid` node:

```
var driverid =getInputVal('driverid');
var newmesajRef = mesajsRef.child(driverid)
newmesajRef.set({
    driverid: driverid,
    ...
```